# Piping to nice?

Tags: nice

I have the following command (simplified):

```
mysqldump <databases> | bzip2 > backupfile.sql.bz2
```

For some reason the bzip2 process went crazy and took the CPU load up to 60. I don't know why, but I am hoping that using nice might mitigate it in the future, but I only want nice on bzip2, not mysqldump.

Can I just change it to

```
mysqldump <databases> | nice bzip2 > backupfile.sql.bz2
```

or do I have to do

```
nice mysqldump <databases> | bzip2 > backupfile.sql.bz2
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**: The correct command is

```
mysqldump <databases> | nice bzip2 > backupfile.sql.bz2
```

---

The `nice` command only alters the niceness of the command it receives as direct argument. It does not apply to the whole pipeline or a chain of commands if you just write it at the beginning of the line.

Therefore:

- ```
  mysqldump <databases> | nice bzip2 > backupfile.sql.bz2
  ```

  will do what you want and launch `mysqldump` normally, whereas `bzip2` runs with an elevated niceness property of +10.
- ```
  nice mysqldump <databases> | bzip2 > backupfile.sql.bz2
  ```

  will do the opposite of what you want, it will make `mysqldump` nice, but let `bzip2` run normally.
- A third option that allows you to run all commands of the pipeline nicely would be to execute them in a new shell process with elevated niceness, like

  ```
  nice bash -c 'mysqldump <databases> | bzip2 > backupfile.sql.bz2'
  ```

However, please note that raising a process' niceness does *not* necessarily reduce its CPU usage. As long as you still have CPU resources left, a nice process will continue to use as much CPU time as it can and requires. Only if your CPU is overloaded (meaning that your running processes request in total more CPU time than you can offer), nice processes will step back and let the CPU give normal or un-nice processes more priority.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to nice only bzip choose first version.